# Remove space between number and caption in List of Figures and Tables?

Tags: table-of-contents

To match a required format, I need to remove the space between numbers and captions in a list of figures and tables.

i.e. Turn this: [image: table x: Caption] into this: [image: table x: Caption]

I already found the tocloft package and feel like it can do what I want, but altering \cftXaftersnumb seems to move the entire list of captions and I need to adjust each line individually.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%%% Add Table XX: to list of tables
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnumb}{\hspace{-.5em}} % move caption to end of 100:
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from tables in lot

%%% Handle extra space in tof
\newlength{\mylenb} % a "scratch" length
\settowidth{\mylenb}{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum} % extra space
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\mylenb} % add the extra space

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllll }     
        \toprule        \footnotesize 
        One& Two  & Three  & Four  & Five  \\
        \midrule        
        2.35& 45.87  & 9.00  & 1.00  &0.33  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Another Table.}
    \label{tab:exp1}
\end{table}

\setcounter{table}{99} % blow up counter to triple digits
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ lllll}     
        \toprule    \footnotesize 
        One& Two  & Three  & Four  & Five  \\
        \midrule        
        2.35& 45.87  & 9.00  & 1.00  &0.33  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Another Table.}
    \label{tab:exp2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You would probably be happier with a tocloft solution.  Otherwise, use `{\def\numberline#1{Table #1:~}\listoftables}`.

Comment: Thanks John Kormylo!
That definitely does the desired thing!

Comment: On second thought, use `{\def\numberline#1{\tablename~#1:\space}\listoftables}`.  Not that a break is likely, but you never know.